# Google AdSense, ads personalization based on GDPR consent settings

Tags: adsense

I've created GDPR consent message inside AdSense page. In the settings menu I can choose one option: to show personalized or not personalized ads, after user agrees with GDPR terms. At the moment only personalized ads are shown, event if user does not give consent.

I need help how to check if user agreed or declined consent message. If user agreed - personalized ads must be shown, otherwise - non personalized.

I know that, this option can be changed by setting:

`googletag.pubads().setPrivacySettings({nonPersonalizedAds: true})`

I cannot find any related cookie. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.